# Minikube - how to increase ephemeral storage

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to set up a copy of our app on my development machine using minikube. But I get an error showing up in minikube dashboard:

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient ephemeral-storage
```

Any ideas as to how I fix this?

The relevant part of the yaml configuration file looks like so:

```
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 500Mi
        cpu: 1
        ephemeral-storage: 16Gi
      limits:
        memory: 4Gi
        cpu: 1
        ephemeral-storage: 32Gi
```

I have tried assigning extra disk space at startup with the following but the error persists:

```
minikube start --disk-size 64g
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is that minikube [can't resize](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1002) the VM disk.

Depending on the type Hypervisor driver (xhyve, virtualbox, hyper-v) and disk type (qcow2, sparse, raw, etc.) resizing the VM disk will be different. For example, for if you have:

```
/Users/username/.minikube/machines/minikube/minikube.rawdisk
```

You can do something like this:

```
$ cd /Users/username/.minikube/machines/minikube
$ mv minikube.rawdisk minikube.img
$ hdiutil resize -size 64g minikube.img
$ mv minikube.img minikube.rawdisk
$ minikube start
$ minikube ssh
```

Then in the VM:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/vda1 # <-- or the disk of your VM
```

Otherwise, if you don't care about the data in your VM:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.minikube
$ minikube start --disk-size 64g
```

Comment: Sadly the minikube VM i had ran `Buildroot` which did not contain the `resize2fs` binary (nor did it have a package manager!) so the latter command to remove the `.minikube` directory was the only way to go for me

Comment: I also had the issue that resize2fs was not installed so I opted for a live cd: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78182935/2298744