# how to resize filesytem for minikube vmdisk

Tags: minikube

I created a vmware virtual machine for minikube with initial disk size 5g. When it almost is used up. I expand the vm disk to 20G, and need to resize the root fs to 20g as well.

**I could not find "resize2fs" and were not able to find any package mangement tools.**

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            7347196   480616   6866580   7% /
devtmpfs         4007536        0   4007536   0% /dev
tmpfs            4081772       84   4081688   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            4081772    10036   4071736   1% /run
tmpfs            4081772        0   4081772   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            4081772       12   4081760   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1        4412800  3777468    363360  92% /mnt/sda1
vmhgfs-fuse    239838052 71787188 168050864  30% /mnt/hgfs
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   20G  0 disk 
`-sda1   8:1    0  4.9G  0 part /mnt/sda1
sr0     11:0    1  151M  0 rom
```

Comment: What is the OS on that vmware virtual machine and what is the FS type? how did you create it?  Am I right that you have installed VMware, created some Linux VM (virtualized) and installed minikube there?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is not 100% clear, but it really looks like you have installed minikube "inside" the virtual machine that runs some minimal linux distro.

[Minikube Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/) describes that you don't require creating a separate VM to install it. You just need to have  Hypervisor like Virtualbox or KVM.
Technically, you can run Minikube even without Hypervisor, so K8s components will be ran on the host and not on a VM (in case you have Docker and Linux installed).

As far as I understood from the description, you don't have e2fsprogs installed (resize2fs is a part of that bundle) as well as any package management tool.
In such a case you can try at least two options:

**Option 1**.
Install the `resize2fs` from [Git repo](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git)

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git
cd e2fsprogs
mkdir build; cd build
make
make check
sudo make install
```

I have just checked that on my VM (ubuntu) and it works; however, it may happen that you'll have to install `build essential` package in order to have a C compiler on that machine and a git in order to fetch the repo.

**Option 2**. 
Copy all the needed stuff from your host machine with `scp` / `rsync` or similar tools. Drawback is that you may have copying some additional libraries.

If you run some minimal Ubuntu on VM, you can try installing [apt from scratch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860375/installing-apt-get). Just download actual version from their [main pool](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/) .

Hope that is the info you've been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

While Nick has provided two solid options to address your situation, let me introduce a third option that might suit your needs.

## Option 3: Utilize a Linux Live CD with GParted

I personally opted for linux Mint since Gparted is already included. There are also live CDs containing just Gparted: https://gparted.org/livecd.php

I like this solution the most since we do not have to alter the installation of Minikube while also being the easiest, quickest and safest one