# I getting always" no space left on device" issue in minikube even system have free space , how to resolve?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm running minikube (version: v1.10.1) with Helm 3 in a local system with ubuntu-16.04 and docker version 19.03.8. Currently, I'm getting a "no space left" issue even when the local disk has more than enough space.

How can I increase the space? This is the POD describe details:

```
  Normal   Scheduled  3m41s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/greeter-5fb8ccb96b-zwzfc to minikube
  Warning  Failed     108s                 kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "12345.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/micro:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob679392224: no space left on device
  Warning  Failed     55s (x2 over 108s)   kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     55s                  kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "12345.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/micro:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob816503247: no space left on device
  Normal   BackOff    41s (x2 over 107s)   kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "12345.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/micro:latest"
  Warning  Failed     41s (x2 over 107s)   kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    27s (x3 over 3m40s)  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "12345.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/micro:latest"
```

Comment: Can you check your inodes usage, please? (`df -i`)

Comment: seems lot of free space already is there `Filesystem /dev/sda1, Inodes 6111232 , IUsed 194078, IFree 5917154,  IUse% 4%, /

Comment: Are you checking the space on the host OS or inside the minikube VM? Space must be checked inside the VM. You need to connect to it with `minikube ssh` and then check the space usage (`df -h` and `df -i`).

Comment: Do you have space in the node?

Comment: Thanks @EduardoBaitello, and KoopaKiller,
I have loged in minikube ssh and removed unused container then i got free space.
 is it possible to increase curent space , means minikube disk space, suppose if fillout current space what will do ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to check the available space on the Minikube Virtual Machine, not in your host OS.

You can access the Minikube VM with `minikube ssh`, then check both space and inodes availability (respectively `df -h` and `df -i`). Generally, the cause of lack of space is due to many docker images in the local repository.

Possible fixes are:

- Remove [unused docker images](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-images) (`docker image prune -a`)
- Increase the disk size on your Virtual Box configuration and [resize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54187396/7641078) the Linux partition (this can be painful to do and may cause a lot of trouble...)
- Start a new minikube VM with increased disk size (e.g., `minikube start --disk-size 50000mb`)

Comment: `minikube start --disk-size 50000mb` if it is running minikube means , need to stop and start with coustome disk size option (--disk-size) right ?

Comment: You will need to stop and delete your current minikube VM (`minikube stop && minikube delete` ), then `minikube start --disk-size 50000mb` to create a fresh VM. Be aware that you will lose all configuration and resources that you have previously deployed.

Comment: Just to be clear, I ran `docker image prune -a` from within the minikube VM (after `minikube ssh`). It cleared out about 8GB and I stopped receiving the "no space left on device" error from within my docker container.